# How to toggle buttons with Vue without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to toggle a sign-in and sign-out button based on if a user is logged-in. I can use v-if effectively, but I have to do a page refresh to see the toggle occur. Ie when you sign-out you have to reload the page to change the 'logout' button into a 'login' one.

Template:

```html
      <div v-if="signedIn">
        <v-btn  class="ml-4 mr-4 primary" @click="logout">
          <span>Sign Out</span>
          <v-icon>mdi-logout</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <v-btn class="ml-4 mr-4 primary" @click="$router.push('/login')">
          <span>Sign In</span>
          <v-icon>mdi-login</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
     data() {
       return {
         drawer: true,
         signedIn: this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn || false,
       };
     },
```

What would be the Vue way of handling the toggle without using a page refresh? I'm sure there's a better way, just to new at Vue and most tutorials I find don't help. Any tips, advice, or suggestions appreciated!

---

**edit**

store:

```js
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import axios from 'axios';

    Vue.use(Vuex);

    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
        user: {},
      },
      mutations: {
        auth_request(state) {
          state.status = 'loading';
        },
        auth_success(state, token, user) {
          state.status = 'success';
          state.token = token;
          state.user = user;
        },
        auth_error(state) {
          state.status = 'error';
        },
        logout(state) {
          state.status = '';
          state.token = '';
        },
      },
      actions: {
        login({ commit }, user) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('auth_request');
            axios({ url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
              .then((resp) => {
                const { token } = resp.data;
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
                const { user } = resp.data;
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token;
                commit('auth_success', token, user);
                resolve(resp);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log('err:', err.response);
                commit('auth_error');
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                reject(err);
              });
          });
        },
        logout({ commit }) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            commit('logout');
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
            resolve();
          });
        },
      },
      getters: {
        isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
        authStatus: state => state.status,
      },
    });
```

Comment: You doing it right so there must be something else going wrong (your data is not reactive). Maybe add store setup to your question....

Comment: @MichalLevý I added the store in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data prop `signedIn` is not reactive to `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn`.

Try using a computed method that returns `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn` instead:

```
computed: {
    signedIn() {
        return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that look in the template piece of the component then? Would I call the method inside the v-if? Thanks!